# Getting model filters to show count of active values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have 2 models that are connected.

Model 1 is *userprofiles* and model 2 is *events*
each user can have multiple events... each event can be active or deactivated.

I have a for loop in the template showing all the userprofiles... but I also want to show how many active events each user has.

```
today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
perm = Permission.objects.get(codename='chef_user')
user_profiles = User.objects.filter(profile__user_profile_active='y').filter(is_active=True).filter(Q(groups__permissions=perm) | Q(user_permissions=perm)).distinct()[:6]
```

in the template I have my loop

```
{% for kitchen_list in user_profiles %}
-- CODE --
{{ kitchen_list.events_set.count }} <--- WHERE I AM TRYING TO SHOW ACTIVE EVENTS COUNT
--CODE--
{% endfor %}
```

my models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    EVENT_TYPE = (('0', "Apartment"), ('1', "Home"),)
    CURRENCY = (('R', "Rand"),)
    OPTIONS = (('y', "Yes"),('n', "No"),)
    OPTIONS_USER = (('y', "Yes"), ('n', "No"),('p', "Pending"),)

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,12}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=12, default='', blank=True)  # validators should be a list

    currency = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='R', choices=CURRENCY)
    bookingpermissions = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='n', choices=OPTIONS)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, default='', blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='na', blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='na', blank=True)
    image = ResizedImageField(size=[400, 400], crop=['middle', 'center'], upload_to='userprofile/static/images', default='', blank=True)
    kitchen_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='a', choices=EVENT_TYPE)
    user_profile_active = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='n', blank=True, choices=OPTIONS_USER)


class Events(models.Model):

    ACTIVE = (('d', "Deactivated"), ('e', "Expired"), ('a', "Active"), ('b', "Drafts"),)
    ALCOHOL = (('0','No bring own alcohol'),('1','There will be complimentary wine pairing'))

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='b', choices=ACTIVE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='')
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    price = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, default='')
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    alcohol_choice = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='n' ,choices=ALCOHOL)
    starter = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True, default='')
    main_menu = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True, default='')
    dessert = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True, default='')
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True, default='')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use model propery

in model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     # You code here
     @property
     def active_events(self):
         return self.user.events_set.filter(active='a').count()
```

in template:

```
{{ kitchen_list.userprofile.active_events }}
```

Comment: Your answer does not give any output

Comment: i have a typo in `active_events`, now i fixed correct record is `self.user.events_set.filter(active='a').count()`

Comment: in question you add `UserProfile` model but in the `user_profiles` you use `User` model, just hard to see, now i overwrite my answer with valid models and method

Comment: @BearBrown That is why I asked for all users or a specific user initially

Comment: Nope still not I don't have a User model, why I used the userprofile model to extend my users fields

Comment: Your answer is amazing! Thanks a million! Should send you a beer

Comment: glad to help you :)

Comment: Bear Brown may you have a look at this for please :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028493/getting-the-amount-of-guests-in-bookings-made-django

Answer (score 0):

Rather do it in the views.py instead of the template to count then pass the values to the template. Assuming you hva e set up the foreign relations well in the models then in the views do the following:
`user_profiles = User.objects.filter(profile__user_profile_active='y').filter(is_active=True)
counts = user_profiles.events_set.count()`

Then pass that as a context. 
Or you can try creating a method in your model UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile:
....
def events(self):
    return self.events_set.count()
```

Comment: in the question PO asked for each user.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: getting an error saying the following: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'events_set'

Comment: When calling the user_profile, use the UserProfiles model and pass the spefici user id so that it returns the profile for that user. Then you can query it for the events count. You have used the User model but the UserProfile is the one with the Foreign relation with the Events. Should be something like this:

Comment: When calling the user_profile, use the UserProfiles model and pass the spefici user id so that it returns the profile for that user. Then you can query it for the events count. You have used the User model but the UserProfile is the one with the Foreign relation with the Events. Should be something like this:
`user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)`
`count = user.userprofile.events_set.count()`
Modify  the `user` object as you were initially  but make sure it returns for a specific user (PK=user_id)

Comment: this gives me the value that I need:
count = user.events_set.filter(active='a').count()

Comment: But not per user.

Comment: Are you calling the user with a specific user id or for all the users?

Comment: calling all the users. but each user has its own events they have created can be more than one. In the view I  want to show if user A has 3 events it will say 3 events and if user B has 1 event it will show 1 event in the view

Comment: user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
perm = Permission.objects.get(codename='chef_user')
user_profiles = User.objects.filter(profile__user_profile_active='y').filter(is_active=True).filter(Q(groups__permissions=perm) | Q(user_permissions=perm)).distinct()[:6]
        count = user.events_set.filter(active='a').count()

Comment: Call the count function from user_profiles not from the user and modify the user_profiles to use to be user_profiles = user......