# Django - displaying each individual user's comment count on a post_detail template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have my comments set up where users can review blog posts and have those reviews show up in the `post_detail.html` template. I would like to display the total number of comments for every user, right next to their comments (in any post).

For example, I'd like it to say `user 1: 4 comments`, and so on, for each user. If `user 1` has left 4 comments on 4 different posts, all 4 posts should display `user 1: 4 comments`.

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

...

def user_rating_count(self):
    user_ratings = Comment.objects.filter(user=2).count()
    return user_ratings

...

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="usernamee")
    ...
    review_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def add_comment(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post # Makes the post linked to the comment
            comment.user = request.user # Makes the user linked to the comment
            comment.email = request.user.email
            comment.picture = request.user.profile.profile_image_url()
            comment.review_count = request.user.profile.user_rating_count()
            comment.save()

            return redirect('blog:post_detail', slug=post.slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    template = "blog/post/add_comment.html"
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**post_detail.html**

```
...
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {{ comment.review_count }}
{% endfor %}
...
```

I've been trying to accomplish this through my model's `user_rating_count` method, but I can only manually select `user=1` or `user=2`, which works, but it isn't dynamic. I'm trying to retrieve the user that left the comment.

Comment: See the following for getting counts for Foreign key [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027863/getting-model-filters-to-show-count-of-active-values/46028022#46028022)

Comment: I've looked at it, I don't understand how to apply that to my situation. I'm still at the beginner stages learning django & python, could you please give a little more info for me to go on?

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
from django.db.models import Count

def user_rating_count(request):
    users = User.objects.all().annotate(ratings=Count('comment'))
    context={'users':users}
    render(request, 'file.html', context)
```

Now in **html**

```
{% for user in users %}
    <b>{{user.username}}</b>:{{user.ratings}}
{% endfor %}
```

This will show, `username : total_comments` for every user.

You need to make a call to `user_rating_count` function from your `urls`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out your code. It gives me an error. I have since done a few things and have come to this road block: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065177/django-forms-how-to-update-user-data-from-previous-comment-when-user-posts-a-n but I'm still stuck.